# Consistency for an iterative method

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I've found the following exercise

> Let $A$ a positive definite matrix, and $b=[1,\ldots,1]$. Consider also $S=\frac{A+A^T}{2}$ and $H=\frac{A-A^T}{2}$ its symmetric and skew-symmetric part and consider the following iterative method:
>
> \begin{cases} 
> (\alpha I +H)x^{k+\frac{1}{2}} = (\alpha I - S)x^k + b \\
> (\alpha I +S) x^{k+1} = (\alpha I - H)x^{k+\frac{1}{2}} + b
> \end{cases}
>
> Is it consistent for every choiche of $\alpha >0$ ?

---

I start by plugging the solution $x$ in the recurrence

$$(\alpha I + S) x = (\alpha I -H) \Bigl( (\alpha I + H)^{-1}(\alpha I - S)x + (\alpha I+H)^{-1}b \Bigr) + b$$

but I can't go on now, as I have those ugly inverse matrices. Any comment,hint or anything is really appreciated.

Comment: What does "positive definite" mean? That $S$ is positive definite? That $A$ is normal with only positive eigenvalues?

Comment: It means that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive @LutzLehmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\alpha I+H$ and $\alpha I-H$ commute, so you can write
$$
\begin{split}
(\alpha I+S)x&=(\alpha I-H)[(\alpha I+H)^{-1}(\alpha I-S)x+(\alpha I+H)^{-1}b]+b\\
&=(\alpha I+H)^{-1}(\alpha I-H)[(\alpha I-S)x+b]+b
\end{split}
$$
and multiplying with $\alpha I+H$ gives
$$
(\alpha I+H)(\alpha I+S)x=(\alpha I-H)(\alpha I-S)x+2\alpha b.
$$
Now just expand the products, cancel out extra terms, and divide by $2\alpha$.

---

EDIT: To show that
$$
G:=(\alpha I+S)^{-1}(\alpha I-H)(\alpha I+H)^{-1}(\alpha I-S)
$$
is convergent, do the similarity transformation
$$
\tilde{G}:=(\alpha I-S)G(\alpha I+S)^{-1}
=
(\alpha I-H)(\alpha I+H)^{-1}(\alpha I-S)(\alpha I+S)^{-1}.
$$
Let $\rho(\cdot)$ be the spectral radius of the argument.
You can show that $Q:=(\alpha I-S)(\alpha I+S)^{-1}$ is orthogonal.
Let $T:=(\alpha I-H)(\alpha I+H)^{-1}$.
We have
$$
\rho(G)=\rho(\tilde{G})\leq\|\tilde{G}\|_2=\|TQ\|_2=\|T\|_2=\rho(T).
$$

Using an eigen-decomposition of the symmetric $H$, you can then show that
$$
\rho(T)=\max_{\lambda\in\lambda(H)}\left|\frac{\alpha-\lambda}{\alpha+\lambda}\right|,
$$
which is smaller than one assuming that $H$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks @AlgebraicPavel I think you forgot to multiply also $b$ by $\alpha I + H$. 

Your last expression whould be 

$$(\alpha I+H)(\alpha I+S)x=(\alpha I-H)(\alpha I-S)x+2 \alpha I b$$

Doing all the computations, I got 

$$(S+H)x=b \quad => Ax=b$$

So the scheme is consistent for every $\alpha >0$, right?

Comment: @andereBen True, there's a missing factor $2\alpha$. Thanks.

Comment: One last thing: how can I check if the method is convergent? I was thinking about investigating the spectral radius of 
which is $$( \alpha I + S)^{-1}(\alpha I -H) (\alpha I+H)^{-1} (\alpha I-S)$$

Comment: @andereBen Yes, that's what you have to start with :-) I've added something in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! All the steps are clear. So, in order to achieve convergence, I need $\rho(T) <1$ which is the case if $\alpha>0$ (and this holds) and $H$ p.d. But we know that $A$ is p.d., so 

$$x^T H x=\frac{1}{2}\bigl( x^TAx + x^T A^T x \bigr) \geq 0$$

since $x^TA^Tx=(x^TAx)^T$. So the method is convergent for $A$A p.d. 

Is this okay?

Comment: @andereBen Sounds good.

Comment: Many thanks for the check. Btw, do you know any book which contains this type of exercises?

Comment: You can find interesting exercises in the books by Golub&Van Loan, Horn&Johnson, Saad, Bau&Trefethen,... to name a few.